# ManagementObjectSearcher query results in Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E

Tags: vb.net

The full error is

> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

I am running the same code on many machines without a problem, the client uses windows 7.

The code is

```
 Function OperatingSystemDetails() As String
    Dim RetString As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Try
        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            RetString.Append("SerialNumber: " & StrReverse(Trim(queryObj("SerialNumber"))) & Environment.NewLine)
        Next
    Catch err As ManagementException
        RetString.Clear()
        RetString.Append("ERROR: " & err.Message)
    End Try
    Return RetString.ToString
End Function
```

Could it really be that the DLL (System.Management (in System.Management.dll)) is missing or corrupt or is it more likely that the client has a service turned off. Does anyone know which windows service it is?

Edit: I have tried to find examples to check for presence of the data but failed.

Comment: More likely there is an issue getting the OS Serial, you arent checking if its in the collection before trying to use it.

Comment: The same problem occurs getting several other pieces of info. It can't all not be there. Can you suggest how I would check if its there? Im bit new to this